# Equivalence between two fractional Sobolev spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

For $s \in (0,1)$, we consider the *spectral fractional Laplacian*
\begin{align} 
(-\Delta)^{-s}u = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda_k^{-s}(\phi_k,u)_{L^2}\phi_k
\end{align}
where
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
-\Delta\phi_k = \lambda_k\phi_k &\mbox{in }\Omega,\\
\partial_\nu \phi_k = 0 &\mbox{on }\partial\Omega,\qquad k\geq 1.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then, for $\alpha \in (0,1)$, we define the space
\begin{align*}
H^\alpha(\Omega) = \{ u\in L^2(\Omega):~ \nabla (-\Delta)^{(\alpha-1)/2}u\in L^2(\Omega) \},
\end{align*}
and the space
\begin{align*}
\tilde H^\alpha(\Omega) = \{ u\in L^2(\Omega)~:~ \sum_{j=1}^\infty \lambda_j^\alpha|(\phi_j,u)_{L^2(\Omega)}|^2<\infty\} 
\end{align*}

**Questions:**

1. *Are these two spaces equivalent?*
2. Do Sobolev embeddings, Poincaré inequalities, etc hold in them? If yes, where can I find a reference?

---

**UPDATE.**
After the discussion in the comments, let me reformulate the question in a way that avoids (hopefully) some issues:

Let $(\phi_k)\subset L^2(\Omega)$ be a complete orthonormal system for $\mathcal L^2(\Omega)= \{ u\in L^2(\Omega):\int_\Omega u d x =0 \}$ composed of eigenfunctions of $-\Delta$ with homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions with eigenvalues $(\lambda_k)\subset (0,\infty)$.

**Q1:** Is \begin{align} 
(-\Delta)^{-s}u = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda_k^{-s}(\phi_k,u)_{L^2}\phi_k
\end{align}
well-defined?

**Q2:**  Define
\begin{align*}
\mathcal H^\alpha(\Omega) = \{ u\in \mathcal L^2(\Omega):~ \nabla (-\Delta)^{(\alpha-1)/2}u\in L^2(\Omega) \},
\end{align*}
and the space
\begin{align*}
\tilde{\mathcal H}^\alpha(\Omega) = \{ u\in \mathcal L^2(\Omega)~:~ \sum_{j=1}^\infty \lambda_j^\alpha|(\phi_j,u)_{L^2(\Omega)}|^2<\infty\} 
\end{align*}
Are these spaces well-defined and are they equivalent?

Comment: Not sure what $(-\Delta)^{-s}$ does to the constant function $\phi_1$ (which corresponds to $\lambda_1 = 0$). If $\phi_1$ is not in the domain of $(-\Delta)^{-s}$, then it belongs to $\tilde{H}^\alpha$, but not to $H^\alpha$, I guess.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I'm not quite sure what you mean. What is the domain of $(-\Delta)^{-s}$? Why are constants in $\tilde H^\alpha$ but not in $H^\alpha$?

Comment: Just asking for clarification. Currently, as far as I understand, we have $\lambda_1 = 0$ and the term $k = 1$ in the definition of $(-\Delta)^{-s}$ involves $\lambda_1^{-s} = 0^{-s}$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki is right: the Neumann laplacian is not invertible because its leading eigenvalue is zero.

Comment: Here are two possibilities for correcting this bug with the leading eigenvalue to avoid division by zero: (1) you can change the boundary conditions to Dirichlet or (2) you can shift the operator as in, e.g., Section 3.2 of https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40072-020-00175-6

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I see: think is a big problem indeed. What can be done if I want to keep the Neumann condition and avoiding modifying the operator? As a concrete model, what if I wanted to have equation (1.1) of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.00660.pdf but with Neumann boundary condition?

Comment: @Zac: I guess you can simply *define* the inverse $(-\Delta)^s$ so that $(-\Delta)^s \phi_1 = 0$ (or whatever constant, in fact): the gradient will annihilate $\phi_1$ anyway.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki How can one do that?

Comment: For example, define the operator by $u \mapsto (-\Delta)^s u + a \phi_1$ for any $a \ne 0$ and $s \in (0,1)$; this operator is now invertible.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee I'm confused: (1) what would be the series representation of the inverse operator so defined? (2) What happens if, instead, I just start the sum in the definition of the operator in the question from $k=2$? (3) What happens, in either case, to the equivalent representation $\frac{1}{\Gamma(-s)} \int_0^{+\infty} \left(e^{t\Delta} u(x)- u(x)\right)  t^{-1+s} d t$? (5) As a fix to all of it, doesn't it suffice to consider $L^2$ functions with zero average in the definition of the spaces instead of simply $L^2$?

Comment: (1) The fractional *inverse* operator (call it $L^s$) would then be spectrally defined by $L^{s} u = a^{-s} \phi_1 + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \lambda^{-s} \langle u, \phi_k \rangle  \phi_k $ (2) That doesn’t seem to work, just think of the finite-dimensional case; it’s still singular.  (3) If it’s equivalent, it’s not invertible.  (4) That seems like it works.  Hope that helps!

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Thank you so much! What is the relationship between the approach of (1) and the approach of (4)? Also, if you don't mind, could you tell me in more detail why the approach of (4) works?

Comment: Think about it spectrally: an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space in (1) is $\{ \phi_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ whereas for (4) it is just $\{ \phi_k \}_{k=2}^{\infty}$ because all non-constant eigenfunctions have zero average (since they are orthogonal to the constant eigenfunction associated to $\lambda_1$).

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee I'm not sure I understand the last comment. Let me rephrase the question: Let us consider $\mathcal L^2$, the subset of $L^2$ containing only zero-average functions and define $\mathcal H^\alpha$ and $\tilde{\mathcal H}^{\alpha}$ as in the original post, but with $L^2$ replaced by $\mathcal L^2$. In this setup, are $\mathcal H^\alpha$ and $\tilde{ \mathcal H}^\alpha$ equivalent and is $(-\Delta)^{-s}$ well-defined on them?

Comment: Seems like you understand.  The operator $-\Delta$ is indeed invertible on this restricted function space where you essentially have removed the constant degree of freedom in the direction of $\phi_1$, and according to Martin’s answer, the spaces are equivalent.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Amazing. Thanks! I've updated the question to reflect the discussion. But, as I was typing, the following doubt arose: should I write at this point $\nabla (-\Delta)^{(\alpha-1)/2}u\in L^2(\Omega)$ or $\nabla (-\Delta)^{(\alpha-1)/2}u\in \mathcal L^2(\Omega)$ in the definition of the space?

Comment: Sorry I did not see your last question; the update looks fine except that in Q1, it's probably a good idea to specify that $u \in \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are. Since $(\phi_j,(-\Delta)^\eta u) = \lambda_j^\eta (\phi_j,u)$, it suffices to consider the case $\alpha = 1$. Since, for any closed operator $A$, the domain of $A$ coincides with that of $(A^*A)^{1/2}$ (their graph norms are the same), it remains to note that, for $\nabla$ as in the question, $\nabla^*\nabla$ coincides with the Neumann Laplacian, which is the case if $\Omega$ is regular enough.

Comment: Hi Martin, How are you?  It seems $\nabla$
 is a derivative operator and not endowed with any boundary conditions. So, it's unclear why "$\nabla^*\nabla$
coincides with the *Neumann* Laplacian." That's why the answer I provided discussed the boundary terms that arise from integrating by parts. Not sure why those boundary terms are necessarily bounded for functions in $H^{\alpha}(\Omega)$ ...

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Take the case of $\Omega = [0,1]$. By definition, the domain of $\nabla^*$ consists of those $f \in L^2$ such that there exists $g \in L^2$ with $(g,u) = (f,\nabla u)$ for all $u$ in the domain of $\nabla$. For $f$ smooth, this forces it to vanish at the boundary since otherwise a boundary term appears which cannot be generated by $g$. As a consequence, functions in the domain of $\nabla^*\nabla$ must have vanishing gradient at the boundary.